# Make a noise or alert when iperf drops connection or has a bad packet rate

Tags: command-line, iperf, iperf3

Help me be lazy. My task at work requires me to monitor the output of an iperf script to check if the connection drops or the packet rate gets too high. I do not want to have to stare at the screen for hours on end and would rather get alerted when something goes wrong. Is there an easy way to accomplish this using iperf 3? Or can you think of a different creative way to help me

Ideally, there would be a way to modify the iperf script or go into iperf and modify the code. I think there could be a way to output the iperf connection status and use a second program to monitor that output for any errors. I am hoping that when something goes wrong, the computer will produce a beeping noise to alert me